# Insert 2 images side by side in itext7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext7

I am trying to insert multiple images from my SQL database onto a single line with a space between each image. These images are retrieved using a foreach loop.

This is the code I am using as of now, but getting each image on a new row:

```
      foreach (var assoc in custAssoc)
      {
        association = context.Associations.Where(x => x.ID == assoc.AssociationID).FirstOrDefault();
        byte[] assocImg = association.Image;
        Image genImg = new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(assocImg));
        genImg.SetHeight(50).SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        doc.Add(genImg);
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you